# Is there a way to check for duplicate values in Excel WITHOUT using the CountIf function?

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

A lot of the solutions here on SO involve using `CountIf` to find duplicates.  When I have a list of 100,000+ values however, it will often take minutes for `CountIf` to search for duplicates.

Is there a quicker way to search for duplicates within an Excel column *WITHOUT* using CountIf?

Thanks!

**EDIT #1:**
After reading the comments and replies I realize I need to go into greater detail.  Let's pretend I'm a birdwatcher, and after I return from a birdwatching trip I input anywhere from 1 to 25 or 50 new birds that I saw on my trip into my "Master List of Birds Seen".  This is really a dynamically growing list, and with each addition I want to make sure I'm not duplicating something that already exists in my list.

So, in column A of my file are the names of the birds.  Column B-M might contain other attributes of the birds.  I want to know if a bird that I just added in column A after my latest birdwatching trip ALREADY exists somewhere ELSE in my list.  And, if it does, I would manually merge the data of the 2 entries and throw away some and keep some after careful review.  I clearly don't want to have duplicate entries of the same bird in my database.

So, ultimately I want some indication that there is or isn't a duplicate somewhere else, and if there is duplicate please tell me what row to look in (or highlight or color both of the duplicates).

Comment: In that case you could use `Data Validation` to prevent you entering duplicate bird names. see [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal07.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using Excel 2007 or later (which is likely from the 100,000+ values) you can choose:

**Home Tab | Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules > Duplicate Values...**

Right-click a highlighted cell and filter by selected cell color to show just the duplicates (be aware however this can be slow with conditional formatting).

Alternatively run this code and filter for colored cells which takes only a second on 100,000 cells:

```
Sub HighlightDupes()

Dim i As Long, dic As Variant, v As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

i = 1
For Each v In Selection.Value2
    If dic.exists(v) Then dic(v) = "" Else dic.Add v, i
    i = i + 1
Next v

Selection.Font.Color = 255
For Each v In dic
    If dic(v) <> "" Then Selection(dic(v)).Font.Color = 0
Next v

End Sub
```

*Addendum*:

To select only duplicate values without code or formulas, i have found this method useful:

**Data Tab | Advanced Filter...** Filter in Place, Unique Records Only, OK.

Now select the range of unique values and press Alt+; (Goto Special... Visible cells only). With this selection clear the filter and you will see that all unselected cells are duplicates, you can then press Ctrl+9 (Hide Rows) to show just the duplicates. These rows can be copied to another sheet if needed or marked with an "X".

Comment: +1 Good suggestion about Advanced Filter. Unfortunately Advanced Filter also takes hell lot of a time when working with enormous rows.

Comment: Thanks, that's true Advanced Filter is not that quick when filtering in place on large selections but it's still quicker than filling down `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)` at least on my system (~5s vs 9s on 20,000 rows using Excel 2010) and it is much faster when copying to another range.

Answer (score 10):

The fastest way that I know of (in case you are using Excel 2007/2010/2011) is to use **Data (In Ribbon) | Remove Duplicates** to find the total number of duplicates OR to remove duplicates. You might want to move data to a temp sheet before you test this.

The 2nd fastest way is to use Countif. Now Countif can be used in many ways to find duplicates. Here are two main ways.

1) Inserting a New Column next to the data and putting the formula and simply copying it down.

2) Using Countif in Conditional formatting to highlight cells which are duplicates. For more details, please see this link.

[suggestions for a macro to find duplicates in a SINGLE column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469438/suggestions-for-a-macro-to-find-duplicates-in-a-single-column/9469740#9469740)

**EDIT:**

My Apologies :)

Countif is the 3rd fastest way!

The 2nd fastest way is to use Pivot Tables ;)

What exactly is your main purpose of finding duplicates? Do you want to delete them? Or Do you want to highlight them? Or something else?

**FOLLOWUP**

Seems like I made a typo in the formula. Yes for large number of rows, CountIf does take minutes as you suggested.

Let me see if I can come up with a VBA code to suit your exact needs.

Sid

Comment: I added more edits to my question to answer your questions.  I don't want to delete them, just highlight them so that I can manually review them.  Please see what I added.

Comment: @phan: Then what you need is Conditional formatting as I mentioned above. See this link for details :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469438/suggestions-for-a-macro-to-find-duplicates-in-a-single-column/9469740#9469740 I have also updated this link in the above post.

Comment: Instead of highlighting is there a way to "tag" the row by adding the letter "X" in a column next to the bird's name with duplicate entries?  I just realized that if I highlight the cell in a 100,000+ list I will have to do a lot of scrolling.  But, if I tag the row with a marker, say "X", I can just use Filter for "X" and see the duplicate entries.

Comment: @phan: Whoa! That is a hell lot of bird watching that you are doing! :D In that case, go in for the first option where you insert a column and add the countif formula and filter for values > then 1.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying I MUST use CountIf?  My whole question was whether I could avoid it...

Comment: @phan: The countif doesn't take time like I mentioned above (It is one of the fastest methods) so I don't see the harm in using it. :)

Comment: If you're not wanting to use formulas, I think you may be able to use advanced filter for this, as per comment...

Comment: @phan: Please confirm the Excel version that you are using?

Comment: @sid I'm using Excel 2007.  Ah, I'm glad you see what I'm talking about now...using CountIf on 100,000+ rows does take minutes...wondering if there's any way around it..

Answer (score 9):

You can use VBA - the following function returns a list of unique entries within a list of 100,000 in less than a second. Usage: select a range, type the formula (=getUniqueListFromRange(YourRange)) and validate with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

```
Public Function getUniqueListFromRange(parRange As Range) As Variant
' Returns a (1 to n,1 to 1) array with all the values without duplicates

  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim locKey As Variant
  Dim locData As Variant
  Dim locUniqueDict As Variant
  Dim locUniqueList As Variant

  On Error GoTo error_handler
  locData = Intersect(parRange.Parent.UsedRange, parRange)

  Set locUniqueDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  On Error Resume Next
  For i = 1 To UBound(locData, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(locData, 2)
      locKey = UCase(locData(i, j))
      If locKey <> "" Then locUniqueDict.Add locKey, locData(i, j)
    Next j
  Next i

  If locUniqueDict.Count > 0 Then
    ReDim locUniqueList(1 To locUniqueDict.Count, 1 To 1) As Variant
    i = 1
    For Each locKey In locUniqueDict
      locUniqueList(i, 1) = locUniqueDict(locKey)
      i = i + 1
    Next
    getUniqueListFromRange = locUniqueList
  End If

error_handler:         'Empty range

End Function
```

Comment: Nice - the dictionary approach could be used effectively for marking duplicates too. This would likely be quicker than other approaches - more like O(n) than O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention what you want to do when you find them. If you merely want to see where they are...

```
Sub HighLightCells()
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual,  Formula1:=ActiveCell
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End Sub
```

Comment: I added more info to my question to address your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Preventing Duplicates with Data Validation**
You can use Data Validation to prevent you entering duplicate bird names. [See Debra Dalgelish's site](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal07.html#Unique) here

**Handling existing duplicates**
My free [Duplicate Master addin](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2123-Eliminating-duplicate-data-with-Duplicate-Master-V2.html) will let you

- Select
- Colour
- List
- Delete

duplicates.

But more importantly it will let you run more complex matching than exact strings, ie

- Case Insensitive / Case Sensitive searches *(sample below)*
- Trim/Clean data
- Remove all blank spaces (including CHAR(160)) *see the "  mapgie" and "magpie" example below*
- Run regular expression matches  (*for example the sample below replaces `s$` with `""` to remove plurals)*
- Match on any combination of columns (ie Column A, all columns, Column A&B etc)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned the RemoveDuplicates method.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
```

This will simply remove any duplicate entries on the active worksheet in column A. It takes milliseconds to run (tested with 200k rows). Mind you, this will strictly delete all the duplicate entries. Although that isn't how the original question was worded, I do believe that this still serves your purpose.

Comment: Nice stuff, is this something that got implemented in recent versions?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of finding unique values is to  use the advance filter and filter for unique values only and copy and paste them into other sheet as when the pivot is removed you will get the whole data with the duplicate in them.

Answer (score 0):

**Sort the range** 
and in next column put `=if(a2=a1;1;if(a2=a3;1;0))

"1" will be displayed for duplicates.