# Create list from incomplete dataset

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with lines connecting places. Each place has a corresponding number, and is placed in a region (area).

I want a list `Node` with corresponding `Name`, and `Area`. Since some data is missing, I make the assumption that a line going from `PARIS` will also end up in `PARIS`.

```
From    To          From    To      AreaF   AreaT
51191   51190       BARUM   OVERL   PARIS   PARIS
51191   60000       BARUM   BARDU   PARIS   0
51059   51074       FOLLO   DYRLO   #N/A    #N/A
51059   51070       FOLLO   DYRLO   #N/A    BERG
51059   50795       FOLLO   NYSTU   #N/A    #N/A
51059   59001       FOLLO   VEVEL   #N/A    #N/A
51059   50362       FOLLO   MYRVO   #N/A    #N/A
51059   50363       FOLLO   MYRVO   #N/A    #N/A
51059   50812       FOLLO   NORDB   #N/A    #N/A
```

What I want:

```
Node    Name    Area
50362   MYRVO   BERG
50363   MYRVO   BERG
50795   NYSTU   BERG
50812   NORDB   BERG
51059   FOLLO   BERG
51070   DYRLO   BERG
51074   DYRLO   BERG
51190   OVERL   PARIS
51191   BARUM   PARIS
59001   VEVEL   BERG
60000   BARDU   PARIS
```

Any tips as to how this can be done in Excel? Any useful functions that might come in handy?

The best logic I can come up with is:

(E.g. For row 3)

1. Check if AreaF contains a valid Area name, not #N/A or 0 (False)
2. Check if AreaT contains a valid Area name (False)
3. Check if other rows where column A is 51059 contain valie Area names (True, row 4)
4. Use that Area in the new list

My problem is mainly point 3. I can't figure out what functions etc. I must use to accomplish this.

This seems to work for point 1 and 2:

```
=IF(ISNA(F2);IF(ISNA(G2);$M$2;IF(G2=0;$M$2;G2));IF(F2=0;IF(ISNA(G2);$M$2;IF(G2=0;$M$2;G2));F2))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your use of semicolons is throwing me off - I'm guessing that's the same thing as the comma we use on this side of the ocean! What is in column G, that your formula uses here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA method that loops through the range and essentially is doing the eval with brut force.

I'm sure it can be cleaned up and made more efficient.  Should get you started though.

```
Sub NodeList()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'First Column
    Dim rngA As Range
    Set rngA = [A2:A10]
    Dim datA As Variant
    datA = rngA
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    'Results
    Dim myarray()
    ReDim myarray(100, 100)
    Dim datR As Variant
    Dim store As Boolean
    Dim duplicate As Boolean
    store = False
    duplicate = False
    Dim cntr As Integer
    cntr = 0

    'Range Column loop
    For i = LBound(datA, 1) To UBound(datA, 1)
        'Find first result
        If IsEmpty(myarray(0, 0)) Then
            'Is Col E valid?
            If Not IsError(rngA(i, 5)) Then
                If rngA(i, 5) <> 0 Or rngA(i, 5) <> "#N/A" Or Not IsEmpty(rngA(i, 5)) Then
                    'Col E is valid
                    store = True
                    col = 5
                End If
            End If
            'Is Col F valid?
            If store = False And Not IsError(rngA(i, 6)) Then
                If rngA(i, 6) <> 0 Or rngA(i, 6) <> "#N/A" Or Not IsEmpty(rngA(i, 6)) Then
                    'Col E is valid
                    store = True
                    col = 6
                End If
            End If

            'Store value to results
            If store = True Then
                myarray(0, 0) = rngA(i, 1)
                myarray(0, 1) = rngA(i, col)
                store = False
            End If
        Else
            'Results has at least one value check for duplicate
            'Loop thru results
            For k = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
                If datA(i, 1) = myarray(k, 0) Then
                    ' duplicate found
                    duplicate = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If duplicate = False Then
                'validate data
                If Not IsError(rngA(i, 5)) Then
                    If rngA(i, 5) <> 0 Or rngA(i, 5) <> "#N/A" Or Not IsEmpty(rngA(i, 5)) Then
                        'Col E is valid
                        store = True
                        col = 5
                    End If
                End If
                'Is Col F valid?
                If store = False And Not IsError(rngA(i, 6)) Then
                    If rngA(i, 6) <> 0 Or rngA(i, 6) <> "#N/A" Or Not IsEmpty(rngA(i, 6)) Then
                        'Col E is valid
                        store = True
                        col = 6
                    End If
                End If

                'Store value to results
                If store = True Then
                    cntr = cntr + 1
                    myarray(cntr, 0) = rngA(i, 1)
                    myarray(cntr, 1) = rngA(i, col)
                    store = False
                End If
            End If
            duplicate = False
        End If
    Next


    Dim rngB As Range
    Set rngB = [B2:B10]
    datA = rngB

    'Range Column loop
    For i = LBound(datA, 1) To UBound(datA, 1)
        'Find first result
        If IsEmpty(myarray(0, 0)) Then
            'Is Col E valid?
            If Not IsError(rngA(i, 5)) Then
                If rngA(i, 5) <> 0 Or rngA(i, 5) <> "#N/A" Or Not IsEmpty(rngA(i, 5)) Then
                    'Col E is valid
                    store = True
                    col = 5
                End If
            End If
            'Is Col F valid?
            If store = False And Not IsError(rngA(i, 6)) Then
                If rngA(i, 6) <> 0 Or rngA(i, 6) <> "#N/A" Or Not IsEmpty(rngA(i, 6)) Then
                    'Col E is valid
                    store = True
                    col = 6
                End If
            End If

            'Store value to results
            If store = True Then
                myarray(0, 0) = rngA(i, 2)
                myarray(0, 1) = rngA(i, col)
                store = False
            End If
        Else
            'Results has at least one value check for duplicate
            'Loop thru results
            For k = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
                If datA(i, 1) = myarray(k, 0) Then
                    ' duplicate found
                    duplicate = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If duplicate = False Then
                'validate data
                If Not IsError(rngA(i, 5)) Then
                    If rngA(i, 5) <> 0 Or rngA(i, 5) <> "#N/A" Or Not IsEmpty(rngA(i, 5)) Then
                        'Col E is valid
                        store = True
                        col = 5
                    End If
                End If
                'Is Col F valid?
                If store = False And Not IsError(rngA(i, 6)) Then
                    If rngA(i, 6) <> 0 Or rngA(i, 6) <> "#N/A" Or Not IsEmpty(rngA(i, 6)) Then
                        'Col E is valid
                        store = True
                        col = 6
                    End If
                End If

                If store = False Then
                    'Both are invalid
                    'look in col 'A' and reloop thru value to find another match

                    For p = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
                        If rngA(i, 1) = myarray(p, 0) Then
                            cntr = cntr + 1
                            myarray(cntr, 0) = rngA(i, 2)
                            myarray(cntr, 1) = myarray(p, 1)
                            store = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next

                End If

                'Store value to results
                If store = True Then
                    cntr = cntr + 1
                    myarray(cntr, 0) = rngA(i, 2)
                    myarray(cntr, 1) = rngA(i, col)
                    store = False
                End If
            End If
            duplicate = False
        End If
    Next

    For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
        Range("H" & i + 1).Value = myarray(i, 0)
        Range("I" & i + 1).Value = myarray(i, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Output looks like this:

[image]

I didn't add in the name but you can do that by modifying the array.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, "*Any tips as to how this can be done in Excel? Any useful functions that might come in handy?*":
Your logic would work fine. However, instead of a long formula in each cell, you may want to consider coding this in VBA. The format would be something similar to:

1. Go through all nodes

   - Loop through the nodes with a **For...Next** loop.
2. If the node hasn't been seen yet, add it to a list.

   - Use the **Range.Find** method, for example, to check if the node has been found already. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638260/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-duplicate-values-in-excel-without-using-the-countif/9638515#9638515) for a good discussion on **.Find** vs. **COUNTIF**, etc.)
3. Do your calculations on that node.

   - Check if Area T or Area F contains a valid name.
   - Use that area for the node.

---

To answer your second question about what functions could be used for point 3: For something not using VBA, you might consider the **VLOOKUP** function, as well as **COUNTIF**, as good functions to keep in mind. But again, See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638260/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-duplicate-values-in-excel-without-using-the-countif/9638515#9638515) for a good discussion on **.Find** vs. **COUNTIF**, etc.

Comment: Way overdue: +1! I like this answer, as it explains the procedure in a good way. Thanks!